# How to set a segment control to change collection cell item in table view cell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell, uisegmentedcontrol

I created a collection view in table view cell and added a segment control on the navigation bar of the table view. How can I change the collection cell item when the segment outlet and action is on table view controller?

I tried this on table view controller but get this error:
**request for number of items before section 2147483647 when there are only 1 sections in the collection view**

```
@IBAction func mySegAction(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch mySeg.selectedSegmentIndex
    {
    case 0:
        print("0")
    case 1:
        print("1")
        let indexPath = IndexPath()
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCollectionViewCell

        cell.cateLabel.text! = nameArray2[indexPath.row]
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Table view cell controller:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCollectionViewCell

    cell.cateLabel.text! = nameArray[indexPath.row]
    // I tried this code but fail
    if AddViewController().mySeg?.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        cell.cateLabel.text! = nameArray2[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}
```

I want to change `cateLabel.text! = nameArray[indexPath.row]` to `nameArray2[indexPath.row]` when the `Segment` is changed, How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `tableView.reloadData()` on Action and `collectionView.reloadData()` on cellForRowAt

```
@IBAction func mySegAction(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch mySeg.selectedSegmentIndex{
        case 0:
            segment = 0
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(segment, forKey:"segment")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        case 1:
            segment = 1
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(segment, forKey:"segment")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        default:
            break;
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 1{
        let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddViewCell2", for: indexPath)
        return cell1
    }else if indexPath.row == 2{
        let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddViewCell3", for: indexPath)
        return cell2
    }else if indexPath.row == 3{
        let cell3 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddViewCell4", for: indexPath)
        return cell3
    }else if indexPath.row == 4{
        switch segment {
        case 0:
            let cell4 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddViewCell5", for: indexPath) as! AddViewCell
            cell4.collectionView.reloadData()
            return cell4
        case 1:
            let cell4 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddViewCell5", for: indexPath) as! AddViewCell
            cell4.collectionView.reloadData()
            return cell4
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddViewCell1", for: indexPath)
    return cell


}
```

On the table view cell class:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCollectionViewCell
    let segment = UserDefaults().value(forKey: "segment") as! Int
    //print("segment here")
    //print(segment)
    switch segment {
    case 0:
        cell.cateLabel.text! = nameArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.cateImg.image = imageName[indexPath.row]
    case 1:
        cell.cateLabel.text! = nameArray2[indexPath.row]
        cell.cateImg.image = imageName[indexPath.row]
    default:
        break;
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: i'm getting this error: request for number of items before section 2147483647 when there are only 1 sections in the collection view